# Frames and rviz visualization

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, frames, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following frame transformation chain:
laser_frame -> base_link -> base_stabilized -> base_footprint -> odom -> map -> world

Where

- laser_frame is where the scans are
  generated
- odom is the odometry regarding the
  map
- map is where the 2D map is created
  based on scans
- world is the frame in the middle of
  the stage, what is meant to be
  (0,0,0) and the very first coordinate
  axis

I want the map to be created over the world while scans/world/map moving regarding the quadrotor. I mean something intuitive, the quadrotor moves inside the stage so rviz must show how the stage (world, scans and map) move relative to it, keeping it in the center of view, fixed.

What must be the fixed frame? What must be the target frame? Why? Must I do some weird transformation or it's just simply the setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190793/frames-and-rviz-visualization/) by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer to this question is not simple.
It depends on how you want your frames and what transforms are you doing and how are you doing them.
Each case will require different solutions.

I recomend to make a draw about your frames and reference axes, what you want, what you have and asking yourself if the transformations  you are doing have any sense by themselves.

---

Originally posted by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) with karma: 93 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0